# Firefox not launching after fresh install

Tags: firefox, 14.10

I just did a fresh install from a USB of Ubuntu 14.10, and Firefox was working perfecting find until I executed:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And then restarted.

Now I am unable to launch Firefox (and the only way I managed to get any internet at all was to download the `.deb` file for another browser on another machine, and then transfer it to my machine using a USB stick), I have tried reinstalling it, but it still refuses to run.

When running it through Terminal using:

```
firefox
```

I get this output (`<username>` replaced with my username):

```
(process:2192): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/<username>/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
```

So what is wrong and how do I fix this (it was also working perfectly fine before I did a fresh install - I was previously running Ubuntu 14.10, but had some problems so had to wipe the disk and install it again)?

OS Information:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.10
Release:    14.10
```

Package Information:

```
firefox:
  Installed: 36.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.4
  Candidate: 36.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.4
  Version table:
 *** 36.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.4 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.10.1 0
        500 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ utopic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: So what are the ownership and permissions on the directory mentioned and its parent? e.g. `ls -ld /home/<username>/.gnome2/{,accels}`

Comment: @steeldriver: `.gnome2` seems to be owned by root, and I don't seem to have any access there... Which is very strange because I don't think that I have done anything which could cause something like that.